# Multiple optional resource parameters emberjs

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I would like to be able to add multiple, optional GET parameters to my RESTful resources. Currently I have one route for measurements:

```
this.resource('measurements', {path: '/measurements'});
```

and I want to be able to add a start_date, end_date, and measure parameter. At any time one or all of these parameter could be omitted from the URL. The only way I can think of doing this is to create a route in the router for every combination and then create a separate route object for each one of the these, defining the model to retrieve. This seems very tedious.

Has anybody got a better solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at Alex Speller`s query params https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/3182
It is not yet included in main releases, but is usable (included in canary builds as a plugable feature) and quiet handy.